# redux-saga some of the rapid fired same actions missed

Tags: redux, saga, redux-saga

Hi there I have a onChange callback in one of the React components that dispatches an action several times through a map call like this:

```
onChange: (items, newRatio) => {
  items.map( item => {
    dispatch(itemActions.updateStart({
      ...item,
      adjusted_ratio: _.round(item.adjusted_ratio + newRatio, 1),
    }))
  })
}
```

and I have a Saga for the "items" like so:

```
  // Updating an Item 
  function* watchUpdate() {
    while(true) {
      const { record: unsavedItem, } = yield take(itemTypes.ITEMS_UPDATE_START);
      const task = yield fork( updateItemDbCrud, unsavedItem )
    }
  }
  function* updateItemDbCrud(unsavedItem) {
    const savedItem = yield call( api.update, unsavedItem );
    const result = yield put ( itemActions.updateSuccess(savedItem) )
  }

  export default [watchUpdate]
```

In other words, I expected that whenever the ITEMS_UPDATE_START action gets dispatched, it forks a new updateItemDbCrud and proceeds to do some API work, but I notice that only the first of the sequence of dispatches goes through. Am I using the fork wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of redux-saga are you using ?

Comment: Hi there, it says 0.4.1 in my package.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue (https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/50) and it has to do with the nature of promises and its use in Redux Sagas core.

**It's been resolved in version 0.6**.

if you want to learn more about what caused the issue I recommend reading the above github issue and also Jake Archibalds article on tasks, microtasks, queues and schedules.

https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: It worked! Thanks and I read the issue #50, very informative and amazing speed judging from the question posted and the resolution date.